# Can Traefik redirect example.com/test to 192.168.1.1:8888 with no path?

Tags: traefik

Is it possible to have a domain/path redirect to internal server with no path? Ie hxxp://example.com/test redirects to an internal server 192.168.1.1:8888

I have my traefik up and running using supdomains but as soon as I try to use paths I run into issues. I've tried `pathprefixstrip` to no avail.

This is running in a docker on my qnap server.

```
[frontends.test1]
    backend = "test1"
    entrypoints = ["https"]
        [frontends.tes1t.routes.test1]
        rule = "Host:example.com;PathPrefixStrip /test"

[backends.test1]
            [backends.test1.servers.test1]
            url = "hxxps://192.168.1.1:8888"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `PathPrefixStrip:/test` instead of `PathPrefixStrip /test` (in the same idea you used `Host:example.com` and not `Host example.com`.